# How to show part of text, and then click to show the rest in AngularJS

Tags: html, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some text rendered through AngularJS.
It's rendered this way:

```
<div>{{itm.Comment}}</div>
```

What I need to do is to show the first 40 characters of the text, and then there should be inserted some kind of "...read more"-link. If the "read more"-link is clicked, the rest of the text should be shown. Just like comments on Facebook.

If the original text contains less than 40 characters, there should of course not be inserted the "read more"-link.

Any of you have some kind of clue on how I can achieve this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Regards,
Kim

Answer (score 1):

You could implement your own directive that will handle this situation correctly and manipulate DOM if necessary.

It seems like there's already a solution that you can use: https://github.com/dibari/angular-ellipsis

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dibari/angular-ellipsis

I haven't used it yet but it is on a short list for the exact reason you have for it.